# How to set text in Different languages using DocuSign API like Norwegian?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign API to create Envelopes. And I use Approve & Decline Tabs.

I want to set the language of Approve and Decline Text from API. (I will provide the text based on language). The problem is when I send special characters in the request, it throws a protocol exception.

E.g. For Decline, the text in Norwegian is "Avslå", but this throws exception.

Here is my sample request for Signer/ Recipient:

```
<signer>
  <recipientId>2</recipientId>
  <clientUserId>2</clientUserId>
  <email>ssiripuram@cloudfronts.com</email>
  <name>Someswara Siripuram</name>
  <tabs>
    <approveTabs>
      <approve>
        <xPosition>400</xPosition>
        <yPosition>500</yPosition>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
        <tabLabel>Approve</tabLabel>
        <buttonText>Approve</buttonText>
      </approve>
    </approveTabs>
    <declineTabs>
      <decline>
        <xPosition>480</xPosition>
        <yPosition>500</yPosition>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
        <tabLabel>Decline</tabLabel>
        <buttonText>**Avslå**</buttonText>
      </decline>
    </declineTabs>
  </tabs>
</signer>
```

Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure if the DocuSign API allows such characters, not sure if you can modify the button text to be in Norwegian.  One thing you can do though is you can have a small image of the Norwegian text you need to display on the document and say something like "click this button if you decline" and have the button adjacent to the image...

Comment: I now changed the Decline text to "Avvis" in Norwegian, which means Reject as workaround for this. The problem now is the Decline text does not change at all. It always shows Decline. The "Approve" text changes as set in the API call. Kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that Decline text does not change even when set using API call was the issue in DocuSign API.

I contacted DocuSign API team and raised this issue and they have resolved this issue on September 5, 2014. :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be set in the [signing resource file](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-signing-resource-file-information.pdf#page=6).

Then modify the data element `DocuSign_Decline`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would be nice if you expanded your ands we to include more details. It will be useful to others even after resource linked is moved or changed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I wanted to set the text conditionally, which means it can be English or Norwegian based on user preferences. I contacted DocuSign and this was the issue in DocuSign API. So it is working for me now.